# Numpy Vectorized Window Operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I'm interested in figuring out how to do vectorized computations in a numpy array / pandas dataframe where each new cell is updated with local information.

For example, lets say I'm a weatherman interested in making predictions about the weather. My prediction algorithm will be the mean of the past 3 days. While this prediction is simple, I'd like to be able to do this with an arbitrary function.

Example data:

```
day  temp
1    70
2    72
3    68
4    67
...
```

After a transformation should become

```
day  temp  prediction
1    70    None (no previous data)
2    72    70 (only one data point)
3    68    71 (two data points)
4    67    70
5    70    69
...
```

I'm only interested in the prediction column, so no need to make an attempt to join the data back together after achieving the prediction! Thanks!

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried so far? Have you written any code? Are you getting any errors? How do your results differ from your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rolling` with a window of 3 and the min_periods of 1

```
df['prediction'] = df['temp'].rolling(window = 3, min_periods = 1).mean().shift()
df
  day temp prediction
0   1   70        NaN
1   2   72         70
2   3   68         71
3   4   67         70
4   5   70         69
```